# How to use SQLite in c# without an ADO wrapper

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado

Is this even possible? All of the aritcles I have read state that an ADO wrapper is necessary, but the SQLite website implies that nothing other than their DLL is needed. IF it is possible, then I would expect there to be code examples out there.

Answer (score 3):

Look here:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers

Specifically, search for ".NET Framework".

One of there wrappers there:  http://www.phpguru.org/static/SQLite.NET.html - this one does **not** use ADO, it's just an extremely lightweight SQLite access library.

There's quite a few wrappers there, I'm sure you'll find one to your liking.

Comment: I used SQlite.NET quite a bit since ADO.NET is just too complication for my need. You would have to modify the code a bit to use it with sqlite3, though.

Answer (score 1):

Question is, why wouldn't you want to use an ADO.NET provider? It's the standard framework for   accessing databases in .NET.  I suppose you could use P/Invoke and access the SqlLite library, but thats a lot of work, and why reinvent the wheel when an ADO.NET provider already exists.  ADO.NET is not just the plumbing for accessing database, it also provides a common pattern for accessing data, regardless of provider.

IMO, stick with the SqlLite ADO.NET Provider.

Comment: Only reason is size of deployment package. The various SQLite wrappers run about 3X the size of the SQLite.dll. But they are still under 1 Mb so will probably go with one of them.

Comment: The async methods of the ADO.NET wrapper run synchronously. This is both _very_ misleading and quite annoying. I would prefer using a properly implemented wrapper then working around the fake async during every call. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/async)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two pages

http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

HTH

Comment: and this [ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/)